Question and Notation regarding Quotients of Tensor Products
I read that "One can interpret $(\wedge^nV)^*$ as a quotient of $V^{\otimes k}$," in my class notes.  I know that the notation $V^{\otimes k}$ is just $V \otimes V \otimes \dots \otimes V$ $k$ times, but was unsure what "a quotient of this" meant.
My current understanding of quotients of vector spaces is that if $U$ a subspace of $W$, then the quotient space $W/U$ is the set of translates of U, so $W/U = \{\vec{w} + U:\vec{w} \in W\}$, where $\vec{w} + U$ is a translate of $U$, or $\vec{w} + U = \{ \vec{w} + \vec{u}: \vec{u} \in U \}$.
So what is a quotient of $V^{\otimes k}$?  It is $V^{\otimes k}/U$ where U is any subspace?  Is $V^{\otimes k}$ the subspace of a larger vector space?  Any help is appreciated.

A quotient of $V^{\otimes k}$ would, by default, mean a quotient by a vector subspace.
But there isn't an obvious way to make $(\wedge^n V)^*$ or even $(\wedge^k V)^*$ a quotient of $V^{\otimes k}$.
On the other hand, let $U$ be the subspace of $V^{\otimes k}$ spanned by those pure tensors where some factor repeats, ie those of the form $\dots \otimes v \otimes \dots \otimes v \otimes \dots$. Then $V^{\otimes k}/U \cong \wedge^k V$ and the image of $v_1 \otimes \dots \otimes v_k$ is denoted $v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_k$.
